# Person Accounts and Non Profit Starter Pack

Tags: person-accounts, nonprofit-starter-pack

Reading [this](http://www.slideshare.net/salesforcefoundation/overview-of-the-nonprofit-starter-pack) it sounds like Person Accounts are incompatible with the Non-Profit Starter Pack, which is totally understandable. What I am having trouble finding is a direct answer to whether it is still possible to install the Non-Profit Starter Pack into an org with Person Accounts as long as you don't use that record type any longer (since it isn't possible to turn Person Accounts off).

Is it possible to have both enabled in the system, or does moving to the Non-Profit Starter Pack require a new organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current answer is that we don't know. The NPSP product team is investigating whether or not having Person Accounts enabled actually breaks anything in an upcoming sprint and I will report back.

Obviously, having person accounts enabled in an NPSP org is not recommended, since the NPSP defines an account model and so does person accounts. Your Foundation account executive can assist you in an org swap, but you would have to manage the data migration.